# could not read data from json using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new in PySpark . can anyone help me how to read json data using pyspark.
what we have done,

(1) main.py

```
import os.path
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def fileNameInput(filename,spark):

    try:
        if(os.path.isfile(filename)):
            loadFileIntoHdfs(filename,spark)
        else:
            print("File does not exists")
    except OSError:
        print("Error while finding file")


def loadFileIntoHdfs(fileName,spark):
    df = spark.read.json(fileName)
    df.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
        .getOrCreate()
    file_name = input("Enter file location : ")
    fileNameInput(file_name,spark)
```

When I run above code it throws error message

```
 File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the JSON content

Comment: {
 "employees": [{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  {
   "firstName": "Anna",
   "lastName": "Smith"
  },
  {
   "firstName": "Peter",
   "lastName": "Jones"
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your JSON works in my pyspark. I can get a similar error when the record text goes across multiple lines. **Please ensure that each record fits in one line**.
Alternatively, tell it to support multi-line records:

```
spark.read.json(filename, multiLine=True)
```

What works:

```
{ "employees": [{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, { "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" }, { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" } ] }
```

That outputs:

```
spark.read.json('/home/ernest/Desktop/brokenjson.json').printSchema()
root
 |-- employees: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
```

When I try some input like this:

```
{
  "employees": [{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, { "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" }, { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" } ] }
```

Then I get the corrupt record in schema:

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

But when used with multiline options, the latter input works too.

Comment: you are my hero, spent ages trying to figure this out - strangely using `.option('multiline', 'true')` didnt work for me!